# Lookup and replace multiple value pairs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Apologies if this has been asked before, I can only see solutions for other languages, and don't know what the correct c# terminology is to describe the problem.

I have a `List<Person>`, where each `Person` object has a `Site` and `Department` string property.

Because of different naming conventions across different ERP systems, I need to read the value of each person's site/department, and based on a match being found in a lookup table, replace them:

[image]

Currently I can code this manually like so:

```
foreach (Person p in pi.People)
{
    if (p.Site == "New York" && p.Department == "HR")
    {
        p.Department = "Human Resources";
    }
    else if (p.Site == "Seattle" && p.Department == "Production")
    {
        p.Site = "Redmond";
        p.Department = "Prod Ax-Rdm";
    }
    // .... removed for brevity
}
```

I wondered if there was a better/smarter way to achieve the same however?  There are around 20 rows in the lookup table, and around 700 people in the list.

My inital thoughts are to go with a DataTable (4 columns, with an index on the "old" columns).

I'm happy to go RTFM if anyone has a good suggestion on a better approach.

Comment: How about some constructive criticism to go with that downvote?

Comment: I think your existing approach is fine--these are business rules, unique to your problem domain/business, so you want the rules to be as explicit and simple as possible.

Comment: Thank you; I appreciate your input.

Comment: Are these EF entities coming from SQL?

Comment: Hi, no its JSON via WebApi2 being cast into a `Person` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a lookup class:

```
public class MyLookup
{
    public string OldSite { get; set; }
    public string OldDepartment { get; set; }
    public string NewSite { get; set; }
    public string NewDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

Create the lookup table:

```
var myLookups = new MyLookup[20];

myLookups[0] =
    new MyLookup
    {
        OldSite = "foo",
        OldDepartment = "bar",
        NewSite = "baz",
        NewDepartment = "qux"
    };

[…]
```

Iterate the records, look up the new values and update the record:

```
foreach (var person in pi.People)
{
    var myLookup =
        myLookups
        .SingleOrDefault(a =>
            a.OldSite == person.Site
            && a.OldDepartment == person.Deparment);

    if (myLookup == null)
    {
        // Handle a missing lookup accordingly.
        throw new Exception("Where is my lookup?!");
    }

    person.Site = myLookup.NewSite;
    person.Deparment = myLookup.NewDepartment;
}
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you.  Could you please amend slightly to produce a logic path if no lookup result is found?

Comment: That depends on how you want to handle it. Is it something that should *never* occur? If so, letting `Single` throw is fine. Otherwise, you can replace `Single` with `SingleOrDefault` and handle a `null` appropriately. (Don't use `First` or `FirstOrDefault`, you should *never* have more than one matching lookup.)

Comment: I probably wouldn't edit the pair if no match was found (assuming no match means that the values are the same across both systems), but its very useful to see how to implement this.  Thank you very much, that's been a very valuable learning experience.